# This computer is no longer authorised

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id

I pretty much never sync with iPhone with my Mac, but today I tried.

I got an error "The iPhone "XXX" could not be synced because this computer is no longer authorized for purchased items that are on this iPhone."

So I did what it says to do, "Account > Authorizations > Authorize". 
iTunes confirmed that I now have used 1 out of 5 authorizations.

Yet the same error appears when I try to sync again. I've tried 5 times.

Some notes:
- Yes, both iTunes and iPhone are connected to the same Apple ID.
- No, I have not changed Apple ID recently. If one specific app was problematic, would it tell me which?
- I am running iOS 10 Public beta.
- I have a couple of TestFlight apps installed.
- I have "deauthorized all" recently. Which is why iTunes tells me "1 out of 5". Only 1 computer involved.

None of the "Similar Questions" on this site seem to have any resolution. But here's to hoping...

Another interesting factoid:

The error message uses the Z spelling of authorize. The confirmation message when re-authorizing the computer uses a S spelling "This computer is already authorised."

Comment: Have you restarted both the computer and iPhone since authorizing?

Comment: I just did now, no luck ...